# Spring Authorization Server - Configure User Info Endpoint - Spring Roles in Resource Server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have an existing resource server that is configured to use Spring user rules as security methods. I am trying to migrate onto the Spring Authorization server and trying to figure out how these roles can be accessed in the resource server.

When the user is authentication, I can see in debug logs that my roles are part of the authorized user details. But in the resource server, I am getting default roles from OidcService and scopes as granted authorities.

I know Spring Authorization server 0.21 has implemented the User Info endpoint, but there seems to be no sample or documentation available on how to configure that, and I am sure implementing it will solve my issue.

Another option that I am thinking about is to configure oauth2TokenCustomizer in the server and then add roles in JWT's claims. Then in the resource server think about overriding default OidcService and parse claims to add roles as granted authorities. But issue is with OidcUserService i don't see any code which can give me access to JWT claims.

```
public class CustomOAuth2Token implementsOAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> {

@Override
public void customize(JwtEncodingContext context) {
    // Load user details and add roles to claims
}
```

}

Probably will have to provide a custom extension for  *OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider* and then modify authenticated principal details.

Comment: See [Extracting Authorities Manually](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction) in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.

Customizing the response of the "well-known" openid-configuration endpoint is somewhat tricky because the [filter handling this endpoint](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/main/oauth2-authorization-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/oidc/web/OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter.java#L98) has hardcoded mappings for which field go and do not go in the response.

I worked around this by:

- copying this class into my codebase and giving it another name, in my case CustomOidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter
- using my custom class as an objectPostProcessor for OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter [replacing it entirely](https://gist.github.com/laurensramandt/f18c2cc7c34e0a5b96eea7a2fb9340e9) instead of just customizing it.

This means your custom filter will supply the OidcProviderConfiguration object from now on.
You could then call the **claim** method on this object to add properties such as "userinfo_endpoint".

Note: I was unable to properly format the code snippet in the second link inside this post. If someone with administrative rights could edit this in, this would be nice.

Comment: I am able to customize the token and add custom claims in the authentication server-side of things. You can provide the implementation of OAuth2TokenCustomizer as bean and this will be called to add additional information in my case roles to the claims in token. 

What i am not sure is about resource server side of things, as this still needs to be parsed and get into granted authorities of authenticated principal.